# Problem with automation and Sql Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, query, automationstudio, automation

I have a problem with an automation:
the query inside has no error and runs correctly, but no record is extracted. If I try to run it externally (via run once and query studio) the records are extracted correctly.
Has anyone ever experienced this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you running the SOQL query, is it anonymous console? Is it Apex Trigger? If you are running it from anonymous console, it will respect the running user's permissions and record access.

Comment: @DevelBase2 this is SQL in Marketing Cloud

Comment: @zuzannamj I see now :)

Comment: Yes is Marketing Cloud Automation @zuzannamj

Comment: I would create another target data extension, update the query target and run again. sometimes if you make changes to the target DE, you have to select it again in query activity setup window. Also is the query using overwrite type?